# Else if in my select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have an else if in my select statement i have already tried using case when but the results are not so accurate

heres a snippet of my scripts

```
select distinct t.MovementDate, t.ContractMovementID, t.GID,t.ReferenceGID, 
                p.refno, t.amount,convert(date,t.CreatedDate) as createdDat
from 
    LIF_MGM_T_Contract p
    inner join LIF_MMS_T_PolicySuspense s with (nolock) 
        on s.ContractGID = p.GID
    inner join LIF_TMS_T_FinancialTransaction t with (nolock) 
        on t.ContractGID = p.GID
where  
    p.refno = '1030642 - 1 - Mohahlaula' 
    and t.ReversedIndicator = 1
    and t.counter = (select min(counter) 
                     from LIF_TMS_T_FinancialTransaction t2 with (nolock) 
                     where t2.ContractGID = p.GID 
                           and t2.ReversedIndicator = 1 
                           and t2.MovementDate = t.MovementDate )
```

So i want a else if t2.reversedindicator = 0 and date = getdate() return results.. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Have you tried using the `OR` operator?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name --Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Enfyve I have but it only looks at the first is "reversed indicator" how would you approach this with the OR operator?

Comment: Use parentheses to encapsulate your conditionals.